# iOS: Watch Kit get current location and show on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I have an iOS app that uses a users current location to show directions/ distance between the users current location and a destination point.  I am able to show the destination point on the map, however when I try to get the user's current location using CLlocationManager, it returns coordinates (0,0).  Below is my code for retrieving the users location.

Is retrieving current location possible on the Apple Watch?

If so, what am I doing wrong here that the location is returning (0,0)?

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;
CLLocation *location = locationManager.location;

CLLocationCoordinate2D myLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
```

Also, I have #import < CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> in my .h file and < CLLocationManagerDelegate>

Comment: did u add required keys to ur plsit like NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription ?

Comment: :( no I definitely forgot to do that...

Comment: @Mr.T I have added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to the plist and Maps is turned on under the Capabilities tab, do you know any other reasons why the locationManager would not return a location?

Comment: Do you use watchOS 1 or 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)willActivate
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.locationManager requestLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if ([locations count] == 0) {
        // error
        return;
    }

    // success
    self.currentLocation = [locations firstObject];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, 
        self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(nonnull NSError *)error
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! For others looking for this answer, leaving out the didFailWithError method will cause a crash, make sure to add your keys to the info.plist on your watch extension target, and enable maps under the capabilities tab on your watch extension target.

Answer (score -2):

If you did not implemented this:
(with attributes inspector or programmatically)

self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES

Or in addition to tell the mapView that the user's location is depending of LocationManager.location

Comment: This is on the Apple Watch, there isn't a property called showsUserLocation on WKInterfaceMap, do you know of a different solution?

Comment: Apologies, i did not read exactly, I do not know a lot about Watch Kit Framework... But hasardly, what is returning LocationManager.location ?

Comment: LocationManager.location is returning null

Comment: In Watch Kit Framework, with Core Location has it delegate methods ? Like didUpdateUserLocation ?

Comment: No, all the location delegate methods are done through the phone device, but Watch Kit has its own map object.  There are several things you cannot do within the watch dealing with maps, but I figured I should at least be able to get a current location.